# JBoss EAP 7.4.0 - standalone ssl webservice client config?

Tags: ssl, jboss7.x

I have a Java application running inside JBoss EAP 7.4.0. In my backend, under the hood, there is some code that makes a secure SSL call to an external webservice.

The team that develops the webservice have given me a .jks keystore (so that I can prove that I am a trusted client to their server) and also a .cer trust cert that I can import to my cacerts (so that my cleint app can trust their server).

I have imported the .cer into my cacerts and also configured my standalone.xml to use the .jks as a keystore (or at least I tried many different xml config options).. all to no avail. The certicateRequest part of the ssl handshake seems to fail to find a matching alias on my client side.

I even went back to the standard default standalone.xml file and instead gave Jboss jvm options on startup

```
standalone.bat  -Dweblogic.management.startupMode=ADMIN -Djavax.net.debug=ssl -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_202/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/../xxx/bla.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=yyy
```

but still no good.

The strange thing is that the same jks and cacerts work find in weblogic 12c with the following config

```
<startup-mode>ADMIN</startup-mode>

<client-cert-proxy-enabled>true</client-cert-proxy-enabled>

<weblogic-plugin-enabled>true</weblogic-plugin-enabled>

<key-stores>CustomIdentityAndJavaStandardTrust</key-stores>

<custom-identity-key-store-file-name>C:\dev\tools\Weblogic_Home\user_projects\domains\myapp\security\bla.jks</custom-identity-key-store-file-name>

<custom-identity-key-store-type>JKS</custom-identity-key-store-type>

<custom-identity-key-store-pass-phrase-encrypted><password></custom-identity-key-store-pass-phrase-encrypted>
```

I was wondering of someone had some sample standalone.xml config that I might be able to copy for my purposes.. obviously I have some config wrong

Answer (score 0):

my mistake, in the midst of all my parallel changes I forgot to check the logs for the case when I used the default standalone.xml file and gave JBoss the jvm params:

```
standalone.bat  -Dweblogic.management.startupMode=ADMIN -Djavax.net.debug=ssl -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_202/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/../xxx/bla.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=yyy
```

this allows the underlying handshake to complete